# Index was outside the bounds of the array. Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am having trouble displaying the file creation date in my gridview table.

This is the `page_load` code

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/"));
        List<Thing> lst = new List<Thing>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath); // you might add NULL check and _ check, if that has 2 elements after split.
            lst.Add(new Thing() { FileDate = filename.Split('_')[0], FileName = filename.Split('_')[1], FilePath = filePath });
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = lst;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The error is on this line

```
lst.Add(new Thing() { FileDate = filename.Split('_')[0], FileName = filename.Split('_')[1], FilePath = filePath });
```

This is class `Thing`

```
    public class Thing
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please debug the code, and check if you are able to get values for "filename.Split('_')[0]" and "filename.Split('_')[1]"

Comment: sorry, i am new to this. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: If there is a file without a `_` in the filename then you'll get that error.

Answer (score 0):

ok, do one thing.. split your code into two lines.. as below :

```
String FileDate = filename.Split('_')[0];
String FileName = filename.Split('_')[1];
String FilePath = filePath;
```

And then check which is causing the problem for you.. then check with your data source to get the filename.

Comment: Please check my post again. i added something